# 500 internal server error, when trying to access phpMyAdmin after installing VestaCP control panel

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lamp, phpmyadmin

After installing `VestaCP` control panel I got a `500 internal server error` when trying to access `phpMyAdmin` (on ubuntu 16.04). For web server using `Lamp stack`.

How can I resolve this problem?

**After checking apache error log between the lines I saw:**
*AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this mess$*

Comment: You could check the php error logs found in `/var/log/httpd/` for any clues

Comment: After running /var/log/httpd/ it says create new file or file does not exist. I have just installed LAMP stack and after that VestaCP and nothing else?

Comment: `/var/log/httpd/` is a directory, not a file -- check if there is a file in there with "error" in the name, and look at the contents of that

Comment: It says no such file or directory. What should I do next. I am a newbie, just bought a VPS server. Thanks.

Comment: Which Linux distribution are you using? (Debian, CentOS, etc). It's difficult to help without more information!

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.0.4

Comment: Okay, check this log file: `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and edit your question to add any output from there

Comment: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this mess$

Comment: This error should not cause it, please add the whole contents of the error log to your question

Comment: check it on paste bin https://pastebin.com/dhAHiGb7 -- thanks | on server I have only installed LAMP and VestaCP control panel and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the error log while trying to access the page. On UBUNTU it should be under /var/log/apache2/error.log there you should see more information about the 500 Internal server error.

Comment: Among those line I saw this AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this mess$

Comment: this error message does not result on a 500 error. I am not sure how your vhost is configured possible the error output is on a different error log file.

Check with 
    ll /var/log/apache2/ 

Do you see any other error log file in there?